# Append Image Tag to DOM, No Image Displayed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am building a site with infinite scroll, and when I append images to the bottom of a DIV, they do not show up.

I am basically appending a tag like `<img src='test.png' />` why would these images not show up? Do I need to preload them? If so, how would I go about doing so?

**EDIT:** Here is the page where it is happening: http://campus-meme.com/ - try to scroll to the bottom; images get added to the DOM but never show up.

Comment: Show your code. Have you checked if the images actually get inserted in the DOM tree?

Comment: Really, how do people expect to get answers from such questions?

Comment: I could show my code, but there is a ton of RoR involved, I tried to dumb it down.

Comment: Check the edit for a link to the site. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just took a closer look at your site.

The problem is, that the parent div of the image has a css style 'display:none'. If i delete this in the debugger, i can see the picture.

It get's this from the mosaic-backdrop class.

Comment: Thanks - I'm an idiot, I was using a JS plugin and I thought it was causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I just opened the site with chrome. I get several errors in the debugger console. Please check them.

For example you seem to have forgotten the $ in line 67 of your site.